# My Pop window displays Horizontal scroller, how to remove it?

Tags: php, popup, horizontal-scrolling

My Pop window displays Horizontal scroller, how to remove it? I am using Mozilla 3.6.3, PHP in Windows, I have an anchor tag with href as given below:

```
<a href="javascript:popupWindow('http://example/english/images/buttons/button_invoice.gif"></a>
```

but when I click on this link my pop window is displayed with a horizontal scrollbar.. so help me to remove this horizontal scroll bar...

> **UPDATED**

I have

```
window.open(url,'popupWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,width=650,height=500,screenX=150,screenY=150,top=150,left=150')
```

in popWindow function,

how overflow-x;hidden can be appended to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `width` to it:

```
<a href="javascript:popupWindow('http://example/english/images/buttons/button_invoice.gif', 600"></a>

function popupWindow(url, width)
{
  window.open('url', 'win_name', 'width=' + width);
}
```

And depending upon your layout, you could use the css as well:

```
<style type="text/css">
  overflow-x:hidden;
</style>
```

Comment: can u elaborate the 'overflow-x' part, where i have to do it, pls give the example syntax for it..

Comment: @OM The Eternity: You need put that style in the popup window you are opening and you should specify invoice image in that page.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: I noticed that you are opening an image, it seems that image width is larger than the width of the window you are opening.

Comment: What does Overflow-x:hidden do basically.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: It hides the horizontal scrollbar.